# android.widget.textview cannot be applied to android.view.view

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the Android official doc for [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

In the third (from the top) code example in the page, there's an example on how to implement `MyAdapter` which provides access to the items in the dataset, creates views for items and replaces them when their no longer visible.

Problem is, on `onCreateViewHolder` they pass `v` which is a `View` to the `ViewHolder` which is implemented just before that. The constructor of the `ViewHolder` expects a `TextView`. Android Studio 1.0 than shouts:

```
android.widget.textview cannot be applied to android.view.view
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I think you are a little too easy on the trigger with the down-voting. How is this off-topic? Care to explain yourself?

Comment: try casting the View to TextView `(TextView) v`

Comment: This is of course what I did. I was just wondering if there's something wrong or was this forgotten from the example

Comment: It looks like it might be a bug in the example.

Comment: I'll give you an up-vote to cancel-out that other person's down-vote.

Answer (score 20):

This is the new `RecyclerView` Pattern. In it, you use 3 components:

`ViewHolder` object which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder. In it, you define View fields and a constructor which accepts a View v as parameter. in this constructor, use v.findViewById() to bind all these views

`onCreateViewHolder()` does two things - first you inflate a View object from a layout. Then you create a ViewHolder (one you defined above) with this inflated View passed as parameter.

Finally, `onBindViewHolder()` is passed a ViewHolder object, in which you put contents into all the fields defined in the first and bound in the third step.

As for the example you mentioned, there is a mistake. The `onCreateViewHolder()` method should look like this:

```
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((TextView)v);  //You need a cast here
    return vh;
}
```

OR the ViewHolder should define a constructor expecting a View object (this is actually more correct):

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {            
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(/* some ID */);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too experienced the same error,and i was able solve by following the [kelevandos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3231532/kelevandos) instruction and also making sure that layout file only contains TextView ie.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
```