# LinearLayout cannot be cast to TextView : tutorial Creating Lists and Cards

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I'm trying to follow the Android official doc for [Creating Lists and Cards.](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450598/android-widget-textview-cannot-be-applied-to-android-view-view) that it was necessary to cast in TextView the ViewHolder but when I do it I have the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

**My Adapter**

```
public class CardsViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Game[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public CardsViewAdapter(Game[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_resume_game, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        //...

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((TextView) v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position].getId_game());

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

**My Custom View XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="cards main container">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue_50"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter you are casting TextView to ViewHolder which isn't necessary, and you are also calling ViewHolder in a redundant way. Try this:

`return new ViewHolder(v)` instead of `ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((TextView)`

The reason you do not need this cast is because you are already casting `mView` under your ViewHolder constructor, or rather you're already defining the view it should expect.

Answer (score 3):

You have those 2 mixed up. Assuming that in

```
// create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cards_resume_game, parent, false);
```

the `R.layout.cards_resume_game` is `LinearLayout`, you should then have:

```
ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
```

and have ViewHolder constructor accept a view:

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.some_text_view_id);
}
```

where some_text_view_id is a TextView in said layout, which will be fetched by findViewById()